# BSM and memory usage

Tags: solaris, audit, bsm

Currently have BSM installed on my solaris 10 on my virtual machine. What I'm trying to do is that I want to measure the impact of enabling BSM (auditing) on Solaris on the CPU, memory.

So after applying the BSM is there anyway by which I can reach a conclusion?

I've the following enabled on my bsm

```
dir: /var/audit 
flags: lo,ad,ap
minfree: 20 
naflags: lo,ad,ap
```

And below are mpstat and vmstat before and after

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would someone please add some tags as I don't have enough points to do so. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The impact is pretty low, even on systems generating gigs of audit data.

I'd recommend you get the dtrace Toolkit and see if there's a script included that you could use to gather the data you're looking for.